Teenagers with supernatural powers
I happened to see a TV programme few days back and now I have a fixation on it. The problem is I don't know the name of the movie or series whatever it was. I was thinking that if I typed in what I saw and anyone recognizing it from memory could help me . 
So here is what I saw, it seemed to be a supernatural series with teenagers having supernatural powers (x-men style) and they are fighting monsters or other evil stuff. In one scene there is this guy talking over the phone to his friend while driving and suddenly an evil apparition occurs in the passenger seat he loses control and collides with an oncoming truck (carrying tree trunks) the car explodes and magically reforms as the truck leaves the screen driver unhurt.
Does anybody have an idea to what series/movie this scene belongs to?

It might help if you could give some more information on when/where you saw it. Was it spoken in english? Was the episode set in some sci-fy future? What country was it aired? A lot of special effects? Animated or actual actors? Was it made for children or for (young) adults?

@origin I got it, it's from a movie ' The covenant' .

You should answer the question then accept it, so that it doesn't remain open.

The movie you are describing is The Covenant. The protagonist Caleb, is the guy driving the car (probably a Mustang) while talking to one of his cousin brother. The brothers are known as the Sons of Ipswich.
